# Prime Factorization in Variables

Tags: number-theory

For how many integers $n$ between $1$ and $50$, inclusive, is$$\frac{(n^2-1)!}{(n!)^n}\in\mathbb Z$$

How can I use prime factorization to figure this out? I'm not familiar with many theorems. Is there a way I can solve this on a basic level?
P.S. I'm very young... so I don't have much knowledge yet.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Answer (score 2):

For each $n$ you need to consider the number of factors of each prime $\le n$ in the numerator and denominator.  You can use [Legendre's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre%27s_formula) to get the power of a prime dividing a factorial.  For example, taking $n=5$ we are asking if $\frac{24!}{5!^5}$ is an integer.  We need to consider the primes $2,3,5$ as those are the only ones in the denominator.  There are $12+6+3+1=22$ factors of $2$ in the numerator.  There are $3$ factors of $2$ in $5!$, so there are $15$ in the denominator.  As the number of factors of $2$ in the numerator is higher, we don't have a problem here.  There are $8+2=10$ factors of $3$ in the numerator and $5$ in the denominator, so this is OK.  However, there are $4$ factors of $5$ in the numerator and $5$ in the denominator, so we conclude the fraction is not an integer for $n=5$.

Comment: as $n^2$ choose $n$ (n times) multinomial is an integer, it is only primes dividing $n$ that need to be checked

Comment: @WillJagy:  Good point.  That will save a lot of work.

Comment: Why is that the number of each factors of each primes has to be less than or equal to n?

Comment: I didn't say that.  I said you only needed to check primes less than or equal to $n$ because those are the only ones in the denominator.  You fail is the exponent of a prime in the denominator is greater than the exponent of the same prime in the numerator, as for $5$ in my example.

Comment: Oh I see what you mean okay thank you!

Comment: Just a few more questions. How am I suppose to recognize which ones work? Am I suppose to use the theorem for each number? Which I suppose not? Am I suppose to manipulate the original equation to solve this? Basically, what's the next step. I understand your explanation up above but I'm not so sure on what to do next.

Comment: You should be able to prove that all primes fail.  Numbers of the form $n=2p$ will work for $p$ prime.  There will be $2n$ factors of $p$ in the denominator.  There will be $4p-1$ multiples of $p$ in the numerator, but there will be three more from multiples of $p^2$.  I think only primes will fail.

Comment: Sorry but I don't know how to do that. If you don't want to explain that's totally fine. Thanks for the explanation so far.

Comment: Count the factors of $n$ in the numerator and denominator when $n$ is prime.  How many are there?  There are $n$ in the denominator because there is $1$ in $n!$.  There are $n-1$ in the numerator because there are $n-1$ multiples of $n$ less than or equal to $n^2-1$